# How to get gps coordinates of LINK_IDs returned from PDE

Tags: here-api

Used PDE query:

```
https://pde.api.here.com/1/tile.json?app_id=***&app_code=***&layer=LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC1&level=9&tilex=537&tiley=399
```

Which returned list of rows each contining **LINK_ID**, it does not indicate the GPS. How can I convert **lat/lon** to **link_id** or **link_id** to **lat/lon**

Response Example:

```
{
    Rows: [{
        LINK_ID: "52493206",
        ISO_COUNTRY_CODE: "DEU",
        VEHICLE_TYPES: "1007",
        URBAN: "N",
        TRANSPORT_VERIFIED: "Y",
        FUNCTIONAL_CLASS: "1",
        CONTROLLED_ACCESS: "Y",
        LIMITED_ACCESS_ROAD: "Y",
        TRAVEL_DIRECTION: "F",
        BOAT_FERRY: "N",
        RAIL_FERRY: "N",
        MULTI_DIGITIZED: "Y",
        DIVIDER: "N",
        DIVIDER_LEGAL: "N",
        FRONTAGE: "N",
        PAVED: "Y",
        RAMP: "N",
        PRIVATE: "N",
        POI_ACCESS: "N",
        INTERSECTION_CATEGORY: null,
        SPEED_CATEGORY: "1",
        LANE_CATEGORY: "2",
        COVERAGE_INDICATOR: "N0",
        TO_REF_NUM_LANES: null,
        FROM_REF_NUM_LANES: "2",
        PHYSICAL_NUM_LANES: null,
        LOW_MOBILITY: "3",
        PUBLIC_ACCESS: "Y",
        GRADE_CATEGORY: null,
        ROUTE_TYPES: "3",
        OVERPASS_UNDERPASS: null
    }, {
        LINK_ID: "52493207",
        ...
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get them from PDE on layer ROAD_GEOM

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore: For requesting the possible layers you can use this request:
 https://pde.api.here.com/1/doc/layers.json?app_id=yyy&app_code=xxxx

The ROAD_GEOM_FC1 would cover your your example:

https://pde.cit.api.here.com/1/tiles.json?layers=ROAD_GEOM_FC1,ROAD_GEOM_FC1&levels=9,9&tilexy=537,399,538,399&app_id=yyy&app_code=xxx

> ```
> "Tiles": [{
> "Rows": [{
>   "LINK_ID": "52493206",
>   "LONG_HAUL": "Y",
>   "NAME": "A45",
>   "NAMES": "ENGBNA45",
>   "TUNNEL": "N",
>   "BRIDGE": "Y",
>   "LAT": "5028847,19,112",
>   "LON": "896815,-14,-80",
>   "ZLEVEL": ",1,"
> }, {
>   "LINK_ID": "52493207",
>   "LONG_HAUL": "Y",.....
> ```